# How to resolve "creates a temporary variable which is freed while still in use"?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement `Debug` for my custom `List<T>` using a `while` loop.

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}
struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
    tail: Link<T>,
    len: usize,
}

use std::fmt;
impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for List<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut temp = &self.head;
        while let Some(r) = temp {
            write!(f, "{:?} -> ", r.borrow().val);
            temp = &r.borrow().next; // ERROR
        }
        write!(f, "[]")
    }
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:21:21
   |
21 |             temp = &r.borrow().next; // ERROR
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^     -
   |                     |              |
   |                     |              temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                     |              ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::cell::Ref<'_, Node<T>>`
   |                     creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                     a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I know that I am taking a reference of a temporary value `r`, which is bad. Is there an elegant and idiomatic solution around this problem?

Are there any borrow patterns for Rust code followed by Rustaceans? I know one such pattern is `std::mem::replace` to take ownership of a value, which works only when we have `&mut T`, some call it Indiana Jones Pattern

Comment: Maybe `temp = unsafe { &(*r.as_ptr()).next };`

Comment: don't do linked list, no need to thanks me, https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/, there is already hundred of question about linked list in Rust, there is a good chance your anwser is in these

Comment: @stargateur I was actually following the same link and wanted to write debug.

Comment: well read it https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-iteration.html I believe it answer you quite perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked [the same question on the Rust User's Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-resolve-creates-a-temporary-variable-which-is-freed-while-still-in-use/51244) and got an answer from [alice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704411/alice-ryhl):

```rust
impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for List<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut temp = self.head.clone();
        while let Some(r) = temp {
            write!(f, "{:?} -> ", r.borrow().val);
            temp = r.borrow().next.clone();
        }
        write!(f, "[]")
    }
}
```

> The reason for this is that `borrow()` returns a guard with a destructor, and you can only access references into the `RefCell` while that guard is still active. So without cloning an `Rc`, you would need to keep all the guards from each iteration around, but the loop destroys the previous guard when advancing to the next iteration. An `Rc` clone lets you access the next node without going through the guard, hence sidestepping the issue.

Comment: What means of `a guard with a destructor`?